# Uncaught ReferenceError: X is not defined - JS parsing limitation?

Tags: javascript

I have these lines in my code:

```
var Y = 1;
var Z = X || Y;
```

Where, in a some cases - X is not defined while Y holds a value.

Though I swear I thought it was working before..

I suddenly get "Uncaught ReferenceError: X is not defined".

Wasn't the || operator meant to support such cases?

It does seem to work for:

```
var X = X || 1;
```

When X was never defined before..

Is this due to some sort of JS parsing limitation? I'm curious to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I suddenly get "Uncaught ReferenceError: X is not defined".

You are trying to read from a variable before you've declared it with `var` (or a function argument list) or written to it.

> Wasn't the || operator meant to support such cases?

No.

> It does seem to work for `var X = X || 1;`

You have a `var X` so the `X` variable is declared in that instance.

With `var Z = X || Y;` you are declaring `Z` but not `X` (`Y` was declared on the previous line).

Answer (score 1):

`var X = X || 1;` works due to [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

It's actually:

```
var x;
x = x || 1 // undefined || 1
```